Ci4 Routes in Subfolders
I know there are several question regarding this but still can't get the answer and still got the problem.
So basically i am using Ci4 routing
I have my controller found under:
app
-Controllers
--Admin
---Access
----Departments.php

I made the route in the routes.php as follows:
$routes->group('admin', static function($routes) {
    $routes->group('access', static function($routes) {
        $routes->group('departments', static function($routes) {
            $routes->get('/', 'admin\Access\Departments::index');
        });
    });
});

I have tried also:
$routes->group('admin/access/departments', static function($routes) 
{
    $routes->get('/', 'admin\Access\Departments::index');
});

I have found that i must remove admin\Access\ as the namespace is already defined but still got the same error.
And i am still getting the 404 error:
Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers\admin\Access\Departments::index

And yes the controller has a method called index:
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
class Departments extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'departments';
    }
}


Ok got it the problem was in the controller.
The namespace in the controller is wrong
Here is the controller:
<?php

namespace App\Controllers\Admin\Access;
use App\Controllers\BaseController;
class Departments extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'departments';
    }
}

I changed the namespace, and also added the use of the base controller now otherwise it will not be found.
